# CodeDom - csc.exe cannot be found

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, codedom

I am using CodeDom to generate a .dll on the fly in my wpf application. (C# code is embedded in the xaml markup). I am having issues with some of the assemblies not being found.

If I don't specify the compiler version it can't find the "WindowsBase.dll", "PresentationFramework.dll" and "PresentationCore.dll". I can get around this by specifying the full path to the files but I feel as though this is not a suitable fix. If I specify the compiler version I don't get any errors trying to find the assemblies but i get this error 
"Exception=System.InvalidOperationException: Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found"

This seems weird as code dom should be able to call the csc.exe to compile. Is there another parameter that I need to specify?

Here is the code that I am using.

```
            Dictionary<string, string> provOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            provOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.6");
            CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp", provOptions);

            CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.xml.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.data.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.windows.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.xaml.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("PresentationFramework.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("WindowsBase.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("PresentationCore.dll");

            cp.CompilerOptions = "/t:library";
            cp.GenerateInMemory = true;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            sb.Append(expression);

            CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: The error message is accurate "v4.6" is not a valid compiler version.  You can use "v2.0" or "v3.5" or "v4".  And yes, the full path to the WPF reference assemblies is required.  Be sure to use the correct ones in the c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies subdirectory, depending on which platform and framework version you want to target.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback with regard to the compiler version, that makes sense. Is there a way to avoid specifying the full path name for the assemblies? The application is going to be deployed on multiple machines how can I ensure that the full path is always going to be the same?